# Given a binary tree, determine if it is height-balanced(difference in depth is not mroe than 1) (leetcode 110)

Tags: javascript, data-structures, time-complexity, binary-search-tree, depth-first-search

While learning to solve this, i came across 2 solutions and i cannot understand their time complexities, please teach me how to do so.

Sol 1: O(n) - Postorder DFS to find the height of every node

```
var isBalanced = function(root) {

let dfs = function(node) {
    if (!node) return 0;
    let left = 1 + dfs(node.left);
    let right = 1 + dfs(node.right);
    if (Math.abs(left - right) > 1) return Infinity;
    return Math.max(left, right);
}

return dfs(root)==Infinity?false:true;
};
```

Sol 2: O(n^2)- Standard Top-Down recursion

```
var isBalanced = function(root) {
if (!root) return true;

let height = function(node) {
    if (!node) return 0;
    return 1 + Math.max(height(node.left), height(node.right));
}

return Math.abs(height(root.left) - height(root.right)) < 2 && isBalanced(root.left) && isBalanced(root.right);
 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to ask yourself how many nodes your algorithm visits.

Solution 1 is a depth-first-search, which visits each node exactly once. The rest are constant-time operations. Therefore, if you have *n* nodes in your tree, the complexity is *O(n)*.

Solution 2 is visiting each node, but for each visit, it visits each of its child nodes. Therefore, the complexity is *O(n * n) = O(n<sup>2</sup>)*.